# Would like to know how to have nested tables filtered?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have experienced some success with integrating a filter code snippet. The problem I'm finding is that the filter will not seem to pick up on my data tables which can only be inserted as nested tables. Not having a great knowledge of JavaScript/CSS I'm wondering if this can be fixed.

[image: Entering the word 'title1' then would only display the whole of the title1 table. Hope this makes sense :)]

[image: Like your JS Fiddle concept, if I can explain: when entering the single letter 't' - the 3 tables would be shown in full, only searching the 'title' row.]

JAVASCRIPT

```
var input, table, rows, noMatches, markInstance;


window.onload = function init() {

  input = document.getElementById('myInput');

  noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');

  table = document.getElementById('myTable');

  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

  markInstance = new Mark(table);



  input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
```

```js
var input, table, rows, noMatches, markInstance;


window.onload = function init() {

  input = document.getElementById('myInput');

  noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');

  table = document.getElementById('myTable');

  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

  markInstance = new Mark(table);



  input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));

}



function ContactsearchFX() {



  resetContent();



  markInstance.unmark({

    done: highlightMatches

  });



}



function resetContent() {

 noMatches.textContent = '';



  rows.forEach(function(row) {

    row.classList.remove('show');

  });

}



function highlightMatches() {

  markInstance.mark(input.value, {

    each: showParantRow,

    noMatch: onNoMatches,

  })

}



function showParantRow(element) {

  var row = element.closest('tr');

  row.classList.add('show');

}



function onNoMatches(text) {

  noMatches.textContent = 'No records match: "' + text + '"';

};
```

```css
.input-wrap {

  margin-bottom: 12px;

}





#myInput:invalid~.hints {

  display: block;

}



#noMatches:empty, #noMatches:empty + .hints {

  display: none;

}


.style1 tr {

  display: none;

}



.style1 .show {

  display: table-row;

}



mark {

  background: orange;

  font-weight: bold;

  color: black;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1
/mark.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-wrap">

  <label>

    Search Titles: 

    <input id="myInput" type="text" required

           placeholder="Search Titles" />

  </label>

</div>



<div class="hintsWrap">

  <p id="noMatches"></p>

  <p class="hints">

    Hints: type "not working", "working" ...

  </p>

</div>



<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">

  <tr>

    <td>

    <table><tr><td>not working</td></tr></table>  

    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>

    working

    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: It works in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wr1yt9o/) with your exact code. I did remove the style that was hiding the the row though (`.style1 tr`).

Comment: Yea zgood thanks I did get that far too and mark.js highlighting is working fine. The thing is the table data needs to be hidden from the start.

Comment: Thanks Ram, the normal table '<td>' works OK. but the filter needs to search out the table nested inside another table if you see it in the html ('<td>

    <table><tr><td>not working</td></tr></table>  

    </td>') ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would like to know how to have nested tables inside tables filtered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119875/would-like-to-know-how-to-have-nested-tables-inside-tables-filtered)

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, [does this suit your fancy](https://jsfiddle.net/Seraphendipity/c4L6s8qe/93/), or were you trying for something else?

I focused on making sure that you add the `show` classes to all parent `<tr>` elements of matched items, and remove the class on reset. Additionally, using $() tags around elements allows you to properly obtain their object model -- it seemed you were trying to do Jquery manipulation on the HTML elements proper.

CSS and HTML mostly untouched. Also I have no idea what the noMatches and .hint were supposed to be -- some sort of feedback element?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <head>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1
/mark.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input-wrap">

  <label>

    Search Titles: 

    <input id="myInput" type="text" required

           placeholder="Search Titles" />

  </label>

</div>



<div class="hintsWrap">

  <p id="noMatches"></p>

  <p class="hints">

    Hints: type "not working", "working" ...

  </p>

</div>



<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">

  <tr>

    <td>

    <table><tr><td>not working</td></tr></table>  

    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>

    working

    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.input-wrap {

  margin-bottom: 12px;

}





#myInput:invalid~.hints {

  display: block;

}



#noMatches:empty, #noMatches:empty + .hints {

  display: none;

}


.style1 tr {

  display: none;

}



.style1 .show {

  display: table-row;

}



mark {

  background: orange;

  font-weight: bold;

  color: black;

}
```

JS:

```
var input, table, rows, noMatches, markInstance;


$(document).ready(function init() {


  input = document.getElementById('myInput');

  noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');

  table = document.getElementById('myTable');

  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

  markInstance = new Mark(table);



  input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));

});



function ContactsearchFX() {
  resetContent();
  markInstance.unmark({ done: highlightMatches });
}



function resetContent() {

    $('.noMatchErrorText').remove(); 
    //Remove this line to have a log of searches

    //noMatches.textContent = '';
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    $(row).removeClass('show'); 

  });

}



function highlightMatches() {

  markInstance.mark(input.value, {

    each: showRow,

    noMatch: onNoMatches,

  })

}



function showRow(element) {
//alert(element);
  $(element).parents('tr').addClass('show');
        //Parents incase of several nestings

}



function onNoMatches(text) {
  $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' + text + '"</p>'); 
}
```

---

Further Nesting...

To address your comments on adding the ability to show the full sub table, one would likely add this line in JS: `$(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show');`. This tells not only the parent table row to display properly, but also any siblings of that parent that are `<tr>` tags, thus as long as the table is at least semi-normal, it'll show the table of the matched items. Try typing "Title" -- notice that it shows both tables. Then try "Title2", and note that it only shows the relevant table, as the `<tr>` tags of the first table are cousins, not siblings.

Also, I modified the HTML a bit. To have it work properly, you either need a parent table with `id="myTable"` that all of the tables are under, OR you can set up `myTable` as a class, perhaps with a few changes in the code to account for the fact that `table` is an array.

New HTML (new content):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <head>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1
/mark.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <label>
Search Titles: 
<input id="myInput" type="text" required
       placeholder="Search Titles" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="hintsWrap">
  <p id="noMatches"></p>
  <p class="hints">
    Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"...
  </p>
</div>



<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
<tr><td><table id="myTabledawa" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td>

        <br />

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Title1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <img data-src-                        hq="/th?id=ODL.53f33f407ba28930afd14f3d9390813c&amp;w=197&amp;        h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav"     alt="Iran seizes 'fuel-smuggling' tanker in Gulf" data-    priority="2" id="emb6E9DDF7A" class="rms_img"         src="https://www.bing.com        /th?id=ODL.53f33f407ba28930afd14f3d9390813c&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&    amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" data-        bm="50" width="197" height="110" />Description1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr></table></td></tr>



<tr><td>
<table id="myTable0" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td>

    <br />

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Title2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <img data-src-    hq="/th?id=ODL.22386d3e20f0b540ee8cc4874bdd4ba4&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" alt="Flying ants: Swarms appear on weather map as 'rain'" data-priority="2" id="emb13B6D9078" class="rms_img" src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=ODL.22386d3e20f0b540ee8cc4874bdd4ba4&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" data-bm="51" width="197" height="110" />Description2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
```

CSS remained exactly the same.

New JS (small edit):

```
var input, table, rows, noMatches, markInstance;

$(document).ready(function init() {

  input = document.getElementById('myInput');

  noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');

  table = document.getElementById('myTable');

  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

  markInstance = new Mark(table);



  input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));

});



function ContactsearchFX() {
  resetContent();
  markInstance.unmark({ done: highlightMatches });
}



function resetContent() {

    $('.noMatchErrorText').remove(); 
    //Remove this line to have a log of searches

    //noMatches.textContent = '';
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    $(row).removeClass('show'); 

  });

}



function highlightMatches() {

  markInstance.mark(input.value, {

    each: showRow,

    noMatch: onNoMatches,

  })

}



function showRow(element) {
//alert(element);
  $(element).parents('tr').addClass('show');  $(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show');
        //Parents incase of several nestings

}



function onNoMatches(text) {
  $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' + text + '"</p>'); 
}
```

[Example Fiddle of Showing Full Table](https://jsfiddle.net/Seraphendipity/pu12ewtg/40/)

Comment: Thank you Seraphendipity. Very close, very close indeed. The dilemma now is that when I run your altered code (and thanks for explaining your alterations) the nested table is not displayed in full with all its rows and leaves only single/separate rows from that table. What would be most use full is if when a word is typed from the nested table - the whole table is shown. Is this possible Seraphendipity?

Comment: @Outtheresomewhere Yes, I'll play around with it later to try that. To do so, it may be as simple as changing `$(element).parents('tr').addClass('show');` to `$(element).parents('tr, td').addClass('show');`, or perhaps another line like `$(element).parents('table').addClass('show');` -- the `parents()` allows you to quickly grab parents that meet a certain filter and use it like an array.

Comment: You see the problem with showing a whole table with a title search. (I'm using the same JavaScript and CSS you sent) Thankful Seraphendipity, I await further input.

Comment: Tried both lines, though still isn't showing properly?

Comment: @Outtheresomewhere Try adding `$(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show');`, is that your intent? Also, instead of the question below, attach a JSFiddle link to "You see the problem...with a title search." or add it to your original Q, for good form.

Comment: Replaced - $(element).parents('tr, td').addClass('show'); - with - $(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show'); - with nothing working in the input or displayed result.

Comment: ...Really do appreciate your efforts Seraphendipity but not working in my page (if only I could show you screenshots) html table 'class' cant be done the - page goes blank. Like your JS Fiddle concept, if I can explain: when entering the single letter 't' - the 3 tables would be shown in full, only searching the 'title' row. Entering the word 'title1' then would only display the whole of the title1 table. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: With these lines code your posting do you mean add or replace the code I already  have?

Comment: Where we are so far Seraphendipity. I Have posted two screenshots at the top of this page - the first explains: when entering the single letter 't' - the 3 tables would be shown in full, only needing to search the 'title' row. And the second: Entering the word 'title1' then would only display the whole of the title1 table.

Comment: Please reply :)

Comment: Hey Seraphendipity. Have had a clean-up of the nested tables and tightened up the code a bit - so - was wondering if you were interested in having some input with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122101/have-code-wich-is-filtering-displaying-parts-of-tables-would-like-to-know-how-t - if you can spare a moment ;)

Comment: @Outtheresomewhere Sorry, I typically only visit SO during weekdays. I'm a bit confused: is this JSFiddle NOT what you had in mind? https://jsfiddle.net/Seraphendipity/pu12ewtg/40/ 
Keep in mind that I changed both the JS and HTML -- the HTML has one large table, and the three tables you gave as examples are `<tr><td><table>...</table></td></tr>` under it.

Comment: [link] jsfiddle.net/Seraphendipity/pu12ewtg/40 - works fine and thank-you. I'm now wondering how to restrict the filtering/search to a specified particular table heading (<th>) eg title heading. Any ideas @Seraphendipity?

Comment: @Outtheresomewhere https://markjs.io/#general Since you're using Mark.JS, try using its filter options. I believe you can use it like Jquery `$()`, so perhaps `new mark('th>)` in your initialization process. I dont know mark.js so you'll have to likely work with the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You see the problem with showing a whole table with a title search. (I'm using the same JavaScript and CSS you sent) Thankful Seraphendipity, I look forward to your further input.

HTML

```
<div class="input-wrap">
  <label>
Search Titles: 
<input id="myInput" type="text" required
       placeholder="Search Titles" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="hintsWrap">
  <p id="noMatches"></p>
  <p class="hints">
    Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"...
  </p>
</div>



<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td>

        <br />

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Title1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <img data-src-                        hq="/th?id=ODL.53f33f407ba28930afd14f3d9390813c&amp;w=197&amp;        h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav"     alt="Iran seizes 'fuel-smuggling' tanker in Gulf" data-    priority="2" id="emb6E9DDF7A" class="rms_img"         src="https://www.bing.com        /th?id=ODL.53f33f407ba28930afd14f3d9390813c&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&    amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" data-        bm="50" width="197" height="110" />Description1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

    <br />



<table id="myTable0" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td>

    <br />

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Title2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <img data-src-    hq="/th?id=ODL.22386d3e20f0b540ee8cc4874bdd4ba4&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" alt="Flying ants: Swarms appear on weather map as 'rain'" data-priority="2" id="emb13B6D9078" class="rms_img" src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=ODL.22386d3e20f0b540ee8cc4874bdd4ba4&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" data-bm="51" width="197" height="110" />Description2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

    <br />



<table id="myTable1" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

    <br />

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Title3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <img data-src-        hq="/th?id=ODL.c9ffada4f6eedff438c5c3c2c26b73f4&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" alt="MPs back bid to block Parliament suspension" data-priority="2" id="emb27B566CEC" class="rms_img" src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=ODL.c9ffada4f6eedff438c5c3c2c26b73f4&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" data-bm="52" width="197" height="110" />Description3</td>
        </tr>       <tr>
            <td>Date3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For SO good form, I'd suggest attaching this in some form to your original question rather than as an answer. I tried addressing it back in my original question, try it out.

Comment: Hi Seraphendipity - thank you I have tried your JS alterations, only not finding success. Is there a simple fix that I'm not seeing?