# Would like to know how to have nested tables inside tables filtered?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have experienced some success with integrating a filter code snippet. The only problem I'm finding is that the filter will not seem to simply display the whole of a nested table inside a table and its details based upon entering a 'title' word in the query/input. With not having a great knowledge or understanding of JavaScript/CSS I'm wondering if this can be fixed. Need more info just let me know.

JAVASCRIPT

```
var input, table, rows, noMatches, markInstance;

$(document).ready(function init() {
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');
  table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  markInstance = new Mark(table);

  input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
});



function ContactsearchFX() {
  resetContent();
  markInstance.unmark({ done: highlightMatches });
}



function resetContent() {

    $('.noMatchErrorText').remove(); 
    //Remove this line to have a log of searches

    //noMatches.textContent = '';
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    $(row).removeClass('show'); 
  });
}



function highlightMatches() {
  markInstance.mark(input.value, {
    each: showRow,
    noMatch: onNoMatches,
  })
}



function showRow(element) {
//alert(element);
  $(element).parents('tr, td').addClass('show');//Parents incase of                     several nestings
}



function onNoMatches(text) {
  $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' +                                 text + '"</p>'); 
}



CSS    

.input-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}





        #myInput:invalid ~ .hints {
      display: block;
    }



#noMatches:empty, #noMatches:empty + .hints {
  display: none;
}


.style1 tr {
  display: none;
    }


    .style1 .show {
      display: table-row;
    }



        mark {
          background: orange;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: black;
    }
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js">    </script>
```

```
<div class="input-wrap">
  <label>
    Search Titles: 
    <input id="myInput" type="text" required
           placeholder="Search Titles" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="hintsWrap">
  <p id="noMatches"></p>
  <p class="hints">
    Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title 3"...
  </p>
</div>



<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td>

    <br />

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Title1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <img data-src-    hq="/th?id=ODL.53f33f407ba28930afd14f3d9390813c&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" alt="Iran seizes 'fuel-smuggling' tanker in Gulf" data-priority="2" id="emb6E9DDF7A" class="rms_img" src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=ODL.53f33f407ba28930afd14f3d9390813c&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" data-bm="50" width="197" height="110" />Description1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

    <br />



<table id="myTable0" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td>

    <br />

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Title2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <img data-src-hq="/th?id=ODL.22386d3e20f0b540ee8cc4874bdd4ba4&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" alt="Flying ants: Swarms appear on weather map as 'rain'" data-priority="2" id="emb13B6D9078" class="rms_img" src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=ODL.22386d3e20f0b540ee8cc4874bdd4ba4&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" data-bm="51" width="197" height="110" />Description2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<br />



<table id="myTable1" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

    <br />

        <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Title3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <img data-src-hq="/th?id=ODL.c9ffada4f6eedff438c5c3c2c26b73f4&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" alt="MPs back bid to block Parliament suspension" data-priority="2" id="emb27B566CEC" class="rms_img" src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=ODL.c9ffada4f6eedff438c5c3c2c26b73f4&amp;w=197&amp;h=110&amp;c=7&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=80&amp;dpr=1.76&amp;pid=RichNav" data-bm="52" width="197" height="110" />Description3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Stick to one post

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.input-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}





#myInput:invalid ~ .hints {
  display: block;
}



#noMatches:empty, #noMatches:empty + .hints {
  display: none;
}


.style1 tr {
  display: none;
}


.style1 .show {
  display: table-row;
}



mark {
  background: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Makes completely no sense whatsoever. I'd downvote this but my rep looks nice as a factor of 5

Comment: zer00ne - Simply trying getting closer to a suitable fix. Hope this question makes sense to a usefull coder :)

Comment: Zer00ne do you know if there is a way to upload screenshots?