# Have code which is filtering/displaying parts of tables. Would like to know how to filter whole tables as one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have managed to integrate a couple of code snippets with some success. I have a query/input on my page, only when the searched words/titles are entered the returned displayed results aren't showing full tables, should display the whole of the title1 table (title, description, date ...and all) and searched for in the table title row/column only. I'm wondering if this can be fixed simply. Please let me know if you need more info.

JS

```
var input, table, rows, noMatches, markInstance;

$(document).ready(function init() {
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');
  table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  markInstance = new Mark(table);

  input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
});



function ContactsearchFX() {
  resetContent();
  markInstance.unmark({ done: highlightMatches });
}



function resetContent() {

    $('.noMatchErrorText').remove(); 
    //Remove this line to have a log of searches

    //noMatches.textContent = '';
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    $(row).removeClass('show'); 
  });
}



function highlightMatches() {
  markInstance.mark(input.value, {
    each: showRow,
    noMatch: onNoMatches,
  })
}



function showRow(element) {
//alert(element);
  $(element).parents('tr, td').addClass('show');
  //Parents incase of several nestings
}



function onNoMatches(text) {
  $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' +         text + '"</p>'); 
}
```

CSS

```
.input-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myInput:invalid ~ .hints {
  display: block;
}

#noMatches:empty, #noMatches:empty + .hints {
  display: none;
}

.style1 tr {
  display: none;
}

.style1 .show {
  display: table-row;
}

mark {
  background: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

SCRIPTS USED

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js">        </script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1        /mark.min.js"></script><head/>
```

HTML

```
<div class="input-wrap">
  <label>
    Search Titles: 
    <input id="myInput" type="text" required
           placeholder="Search Titles" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="hintsWrap">
  <p id="noMatches"></p>
  <p class="hints">
    Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title 3"...
  </p>
</div>



<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td>

    <br />

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Title1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <Description1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Title2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <Description2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Title3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <Description3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I only have a little bit of time, so i can only help with part of what you're asking. I know a simple change to part of the code that could prevent highlighting when there is only 1 letter typed.

```
$(document).ready(function init() {
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');
  table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  markInstance = new Mark(table);

  ContactsearchFX = ContactsearchFX.bind(input) 
  input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
});



function ContactsearchFX() {
    if(this.contextText.length > 1){
        resetContent();
        markInstance.unmark({ done: highlightMatches });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Leviathan_the_Great than-you but I think you misunderstood there. What I meant is for no words to be filtered until there is at-least two letters have been entered in the search box. Highlighting works fine as is.